# Delete String Elements

Tags: c#, string

How to delete the last element of a `string`.
If `'globe'`

is the value given by user, how to store it as `'glob'`.
That is excluding last element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`string.Substring()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904308%28VS.71%29.aspx) method.  Pass in the start of the string (`0`) and the length you want (`Length - 1`).

```
string globe = "globe";
string glob = globe.Substring(0, globe.Length - 1);
```

The resulting string `glob` will now be `"glob"`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [string.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904308%28VS.71%29.aspx) overload that takes two arguments, startIndex and length:

```
s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways. For example:

You can use the `Substring` method:

```
string first = original.Substring(0, original.Length - 1);
```

You can use the `Remove` method:

```
string first = original.Remove(original.Length - 1);
```

You can use the `Take` method:

```
string first = new String(original.Take(original.Length - 1).ToArray());
```

You can use the `TakeWhile` method:

```
string first = new String(original.TakeWhile((c,i) => i < original.Length - 1).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

just use the Substring method.  You will want to use 0 for the starting value and s.Length - 1 for the amount of the string to be used (assuming s is the name of your string).